# (Python) data = "{:^13} {:<11} {:<6}\n"

Tags: python

Can't understand the bold line of code in python:
data = "{:^13}  {:<11}  {:<6}\n"
I know there is a string but what's the meaning of the symbold "{}" "^" "<" in this string?The code is from here:

#Run this prior to starting the excercise
from random import randint as rnd

```
memReg = 'members.txt'
exReg = 'inactive.txt'
fee =('yes','no')

def genFiles(current,old):
    with open(current,'w+') as writefile: 
        writefile.write('Membership No  Date Joined  Active  \n')
        **data = "{:^13}  {:<11}  {:<6}\n"**

        for rowno in range(20):
            date = str(rnd(2015,2020))+ '-' + str(rnd(1,12))+'-'+str(rnd(1,25))
            writefile.write(data.format(rnd(10000,99999),date,fee[rnd(0,1)]))


    with open(old,'w+') as writefile: 
        writefile.write('Membership No  Date Joined  Active  \n')
        data = "{:^13}  {:<11}  {:<6}\n"
        for rowno in range(3):
            date = str(rnd(2015,2020))+ '-' + str(rnd(1,12))+'-'+str(rnd(1,25))
            writefile.write(data.format(rnd(10000,99999),date,fee[1]))


genFiles(memReg,exReg)
```

Comment: Those are formatting instructions. See [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple example:

```py
line_to_format = "|{var1:^13}|{var2:<11}|{:<6}|"
line_to_format.format("123", var1="abc", var2="def")
```

and output:

```
'|     abc     |def        |123   |'
```

`:` - marks the end of former (variable name/variable position) and the start of the `format_spec`

In this example three types of `format_spec`:

- `^13` - fill 13 characters in total and align variable value by center
- `<11` - fill 11 characters in total and align variable value by left
- `<6` - same as above but fill only 6 characters

If variable name is not set (e.g `{:<6}`) only positional arguments may be used:

```py
line_to_format = "|{:^13}|{:<11}|{:<6}|"
line_to_format.format("123", var1="abc", var2="def")

# error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple

line_to_format.format("123", "abc", "def")

# correct output
'|     123     |abc        |def   |'
```